# Action returns Status Code 204 but, AJAX success function doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

My controller is correctly returning `new HttpStatusCodeResult(204)`(checked using debugging), but the success function is not triggered. I just want to reset a text field after I've submitted something.

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#offersubmit").click(function (e) {
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('offerForm'));
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                var valdata = $("#offerForm").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Product/MakeOffer",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                    data: valdata,
                    success: $(document).ready(function () {
                        alert("AAA");
                        $('#offerText').val('');
                    })
                })
            }
        });
    });
```

Also tried with `alert()` and it didn't show anything. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the $(document).ready(.. code

```
success: $(document).ready(function () {
    alert("AAA");
    $('#offerText').val('');
})
```

should be

```
success: function(data) {
    alert("AAA");
    $('#offerText').val('');
}
```

Comment: nope, still didnt work...

Comment: my mistake, forgot to add the data param. updated now